# ASP.NET MVC Drop down bindings and Validators

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, drop-down-menu

What is the best way to bind a dropdown list on a MVC View ?

- Should we get all the look up data on the controller to a list object 
  and then bind that to a Model property and then bind the model property to the View.
  Or
- Should we get all the look up data on the controller to a list object and 
  then bind that to a view bag and then bind the view bag property to the view.
  Or
- Should we get all the look up data on the dom ready and then invoke an ajax post method.
  and then bind it to the dropdown ?

The reason i ask this is because i had done the first approach
and I had Required field validations on the model string properties (properties intended to bind text fields).

Now the required field validators on string fields started throwing validation errors on the HTTPGET method itself because I am passing the model to the HTTP Get controller method, which is not expected.
I wanted them to fire on entering some data and click on save (while calling HTTP POST) method only.

Please advice, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please send some code snippet for clarity. How many fields does your model have?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpPost to fetch the data using List Object. All the validations should be applied on the model itself and as per the DRY principle, no further UI validations should be required.